# Save a named sheet from one workbook to a new workbook in the same folder

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I would like to be able to

1. take a sheet called "data" in a given workbook called
   "original_data.xlsm",
2. copy it conditionally (using Autofilter or
       something else), say only those rows where column C was "dog"
3. Create a new workbook, in the same folder as the original book, called dog.xlsm and save the copied stuff into
       a new sheet called "dog data".
4. Then repeat with a different filter.So for example copy and
   autofilter if column C was "cat" and create a workbook "cat.xlsm",  in the same folder as the original book, with a sheet called "cat_data" containing some filtered data.

I've been making incorrect attempts for three days now and would appreciate some help. Here is what I have done so far.

```
Workbooks.Add
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
wb.Sheets("data").SaveAs Workbooks(GetBook).Path & "\dog" 

Workbooks("dog.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=dog"
```

But it's not working. :(

Comment: What do you mean... 'Not working'?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s) will get you started

Comment: Is this to be a macro in the workbook "original_data.xlsm"?

Comment: @RBarryYoung The macro is in some third workbook. Ok.. I see where this is going

Comment: @Sam It's creating some empty workbooks. Not copying the data.

Comment: @Amatya I don't see anywhere in your code where you are trying to copy data. Which line are you expecting the data to copy? (maybe you should record a macro doing what you want, then look at the code)

Comment: @Sam.. oops I forgot to write the command in the quesion. I'll fix itnow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to set wb to "original_data.xlsm", but your first line is making the new workbook the active workbook.

```
Workbooks.Add
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```

See if this helps.

```
Sub sheetCopy()
    Dim wbS As Workbook, wbT As Workbook
    Dim wsS As Worksheet, wsT As Worksheet

    Set wbS = ThisWorkbook 'workbook that holds this code
    Set wsS = wbS.Worksheets("Data")

    wsS.Copy
    Set wbT = ActiveWorkbook 'assign reference asap

    Set wsT = wbT.Worksheets("Data")
    wsT.Name = "Dog Data" 'rename sheet

    wbT.SaveAs wbS.Path & "\dog.xlsx" 'save new workbook
    wsT.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=dog"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I absolutely fear using activeworkbook and activeworksheets cuz I can't keep track of what's active. I am working between 4 different workbooks with 6 sheets each and it's a kind of a mess. Would you be able to tell me how to do this without referencing an active workbook.. maybe using the full name each time? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  And you're quite right to stay away from activeworkbook/activesheet as much as possible, and use direct references instead - I've modified my answer to illustrate some examples.  Note:  the line following `wsS.Copy` is one of the few instances where `ActiveWorkbook` is unavoidable.